# Young adult fantasy series from 80s about a girl transported to a different reality

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, young-adult

Looking for a series I read when I was in middle school 20-25 years ago. All I remember is a girl visiting an older man on her way home from school is accidentally transported to a different reality.

Time passes more quickly for her than this world. I think she was gone 6 months for her, but more like minutes here. She has to survive and there is some type of fighting. I think it was a somewhat primitive world. She was or became an archer.

Comment: not the Narnia series, by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like Josepha Sherman's ["*The Secret of the Unicorn Queen*"](https://www.goodreads.com/series/63387-the-secret-of-the-unicorn-queen) series. In the first book ([*Swept Away and Sun Blind*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/499248.The_Secret_of_the_Unicorn_Queen_Vol_1)), the protagonist falls through a portal to a fantasy realm while visiting an older male mentor figure (a teacher, perhaps?) after school.

> When her eccentric friend Dr. Reit invents an amazing transport into other worlds, Sheila McCarthy accidentally falls through the portal into the kingdom of Arren. There, Sheila finds herself part of a band of warrior-women. Astride unicorns, they gallop toward a dazzling city made of marble. But will they arrive in time to stop the evil king and his wicked wizard henchman from carrying out their deadly plans? And will Sheila *ever* be able to return home?